# Display notification pop-up box on open-source CRM

Tags: javascript, php, crm, vtiger

I am using a vtiger Crm system and I would like to use the pop up notification to display my own messages. I wrote an event handler that triggers after model save, in this handler I would like to call the notification box with my own message.

Here is a working example that is from the 'Products' module handlers, this code was pre-written, it checks if there were duplicate item numbers and shows a message 'LBL_DUPLICATE_item_number' in the pop-up box

```
    class Products_DuplicateItemNumber_Handler
{
    /**
     * EditViewPreSave handler function.
     *
     * @param App\EventHandler $eventHandler
     */
    public function editViewPreSave(App\EventHandler $eventHandler)
    {
        $recordModel = $eventHandler->getRecordModel();
        $response = ['result' => true];
        $fieldModel = $recordModel->getModule()->getFieldByName('item_number');
        if ($fieldModel->isViewable() && ($item_number = $recordModel->get('item_number'))) {
            $queryGenerator = new \App\QueryGenerator($recordModel->getModuleName());
            $queryGenerator->setStateCondition('All');
            $queryGenerator->setFields(['id'])->permissions = false;
            $queryGenerator->addCondition($fieldModel->getName(), $item_number, 'e');
            if ($recordModel->getId()) {
                $queryGenerator->addCondition('id', $recordModel->getId(), 'n');
            }
            if ($queryGenerator->createQuery()->exists()) {
                $response = [
                    'result' => false,
                    'hoverField' => 'item_number',
                    'message' => App\Language::translate('LBL_DUPLICATE_item_number', $recordModel->getModuleName())
                ];
            }
        }
        return $response;
    }
}
```

However, when i try to return $respone in 'editViewPreSave' of another module, nothing happens.

After some digging around i found out that the system uses 'Pnotify' library to show the pop up message, and i belive it's being called in a js file called 'edit.js' in this path 'public_html/layouts/basic/modules/Vtiger/resources'

```
preSaveValidation: function (form) {
            const aDeferred = $.Deferred();
            if (form.find('#preSaveValidation').val()) {
                document.progressLoader = $.progressIndicator({
                    message: app.vtranslate('JS_SAVE_LOADER_INFO'),
                    position: 'html',
                    blockInfo: {
                        enabled: true
                    }
                });
                let formData = new FormData(form[0]);
                formData.append('mode', 'preSaveValidation');
                AppConnector.request({
                    async: false,
                    url: 'index.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: formData,
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false
                })
                    .done((data) => {
                        document.progressLoader.progressIndicator({ mode: 'hide' });
                        let response = data.result;
                        for (let i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                            if (response[i].result !== true) {
                                app.showNotify({
                                    text: response[i].message ? response[i].message : app.vtranslate('JS_ERROR'),
                                    type: 'error'
                                });
                                if (response[i].hoverField != undefined) {
                                    form.find('[name="' + response[i].hoverField + '"]').focus();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        aDeferred.resolve(data.result.length <= 0);
                    })
                    .fail((textStatus, errorThrown) => {
                        document.progressLoader.progressIndicator({ mode: 'hide' });
                        app.showNotify({
                            text: app.vtranslate('JS_ERROR'),
                            type: 'error'
                        });
                        app.errorLog(textStatus, errorThrown);
                        aDeferred.resolve(false);
                    });
            } else {
                aDeferred.resolve(true);
            }

            return aDeferred.promise();
        },
```

I believe that 'app.showNotify' is the function called to display the pop-up box, yet i'm not sure how to replicate the code for my own use, i would like to know the best approach to do this

Comment: What vtiger version are you using? The latest version now is 7.4. From the code you share I think that is a 6.x.

Comment: Also, remember to register your eventhandler and you should also register a callback for the JS pre save event.